# DGS pre-loading with filter

Tags: java, graphql, netflix-dgs

Let's say I have the following schema

```
type Query {
  shows: [Show]
}

type Show {
  # The showId may or may not be there, depending on the scenario.
  showId: ID
  title: String
  reviews(filter: MyFilter): [Review]
}

type Review {
  starRating: Int
  text: String
}
```

I want to use Netflix DGS [pre-loading](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/context-passing/#pre-loading) to fetch reviews in one DB query with the shows as I can easily join it in the DB. Moreover implementing it effectively using DataLoaders is far from straightforward. The question is how to access the review filter `MyFilter` from the shows fetcher?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right,

There are several possible ways to obtain arguments.

DataFetchingEnvironment should contain all needed info

1. Getting argument by name
   `MyFilter dfe = dfe.getArgument("filter");`
   where `dfe` instance of `DataFetchingEnvironment` that should be passed to dataFetcher. Like it is done in DGS example..

```
@DgsData(parentType = "Query", field = "shows")
public DataFetcherResult<List<Show>> shows(DataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
  dfe.getSelectionSet().contains("reviews")
....
```

2. Getting all available arguments via `DataFetchingEnvironment` method
   `Map<String, Object> getArguments()`. It should return the arguments that have been passed in via the graphql query.
3. If any previous options don't suitable, then there is one more.

Getting `DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet` via `DataFetchingEnvironment` method `getSelectionSet()`

`DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet` has a method

```
Map<String,Map<String,Object>> getArguments()
```

It returns a map of the arguments for each field in the selection set.

Comment: Thanks, 
1. returns the filter of the `shows` query 
2. unfortunately returns "raw" GraphQL Objects. For example, query variables are not resolved. 3. I can't find the methods you are describing but I suspect they will have the same issue as 2.